# HTML and Apache2 dont play mp4 video

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have problem with playing mp4 video in web-brower on localhost on Debian 8...I use Apache 2 with html....
This is my index.html in /var/www/html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="150927_NOAA2422_0750_0758_C2.1_ca.mp4" type="video/mp4">


</video>

</body>
</html>
```

In the same path is video file too.

I used .htaccess in /var/www/html with this configuration:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

and change in apache2.conf AllowOverride None to All

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then service apache2 restart...

Now when I type 127.0.0.1 to browser I get window of video but with "No video with supported format and MIME type found"

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you testing with? I wouldn't be surprised if Debian didn't come with one that could handle mp4 video due to the licensing issues around it. Have you successfully watched mp4 videos on other websites? Have you successfully watched the videos on your Debian box from another system which does support the format (e.g. Chrome/Windows or Safari/iOS)?

Comment: Hello...I use iceweasel (it is mozilla firefox for debian).. I see mp4 videos on youtube without problem...I used Chrome and nothing too...

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue on my Raspberry PI and it turns out it was a case sensitive issue in the path of the URL.

http://www.vallisoftware.com/SpeechEditor/shared/SpeechEditorReview.mp4

http://www.vallisoftware.com/SpeechEditor/Shared/SpeechEditorReview.mp4

The top link didn't work but the bottom link did because the folder was named Shared not shared.

I didn't need a .htaccess or didn't need to modify the a .conf file either.